# How to prove the equivalence of adjoint pairs and triangular identities of unit and counit?

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory, solution-verification, adjoint-functors

We know that and adjoint pair $F\dashv G$ between two categories $\textsf{C}$ and $\textsf{D}$ is equivalent to give a natural transformation $\eta:1_{\textsf{C}}\to GF$ with universal property, and in the same fashion $\varepsilon:FG\to1_{\textsf{D}}$. But there is also a fourth equivalent condition which is giving me some trouble. Indeed $F\dashv G$ is also equivalent to ask for natural transformations $\eta$ and $\varepsilon$ to exist as above, but with the universal property replaced by triangular identities:

$$G\varepsilon_A\eta_{GA}=1_{GA}\qquad\varepsilon_{FB}F\eta_{B}=1_{FB}$$

(I'm not able to draw the triangles properly on latex).

I'm not really sure on how to define the bijection
$$\varphi_{AB}:\textsf{D}(B, GA)\to\textsf{C}(FB,A)$$
The only idea I came up with is:
$$\varphi_{AB}(v)=\varepsilon_A\circ Fv$$
and as candidate inverse:
$$\varphi^{-1}_{AB}(u)=Gu\circ \eta_{B}$$
But I'm not really sure on how to use triangular identities in order to show this definition works, assuming is the right one. If we take $A=FB$ then it clearly works, as well as taking $B=GA$ but there's no reason for a generic object $A$ in $\textsf{C}$ to be written as $FB$ for a certain $B$ in $\textsf{D}$ and viceversa.

Comment: Where do you get stuck? You defined two maps in different directions; they are mutually inverses if and only if the triangle identities hold, because $\epsilon_A \circ F(Gu\circ \eta_B) = \epsilon_A\circ FGu\circ F\eta_B = u\circ \epsilon_{FB} \circ F\eta_B$. Similarly, the composition in the other direction is a bijection.

Comment: I would say I wasn't watching at the proper diagram

Comment: You can either look at any book on category theory, or (even better) use the Yoneda Lemma to deduce the equivalence. Notice that $\hom(F(x),-) \to \hom(x,G(-))$ is a morphism from a representable functor, hence is determed by an element of $\hom(x,G(F(x))$, etc.